# How to download Android SDK using sdkmanager (Linux)

Tags: linux, android-studio

I went to https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads and downloaded the Android Studio command line tools. It says there that I can also use the included **sdkmanager** tool to download other Android SDK Packages.

I downloaded the SDK tools and went to ~/android_sdk/tools/bin. I typed in

```
./sdkmanager --list
```

(as instructed by the user guide [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager)). But the sdkmanager returned an error that said that I don't have JAVA_HOME in my PATH. I went ahead to add JAVA_HOME to my environment variable text files.

However, after trying the

```
./sdkmanager --list
```

command again. This time it returned this error instead:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml    /bind/annotation/XmlSchema
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:117)
at com.android.sdklib.tool.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
... 5 more
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.